# JavaScript, forEach array of object stop at condition

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects called `columns` and a array of strings values called `keys`

I'm trying to execute some code when `col.name` be !== to the value of `key`

```
    columns.forEach((col, i) => {
      if (col.name !== keys[i]) {
          console.log('yes, I entered the if statement')
        //do something here
      }
    });
```

The loop ends but no code is being executed, except the console log inside. I want to stop at first `!==`, not to loop the entires values of `columns`
How can I do it? I read the use of every, or a simple for loop but I can't do it with an array of object.

Comment: Or a simple `for` loop.

Comment: especially since foreach instruction is much slower than for.

Comment: I'd say, if you want to `find` certain element and do thing on it, do not use `forEach`. (nor `some` as Nina's answer says.) Although it'd probably never change the behavior, better keep the intent clear.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I did it with a for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return `true` to stop the iteration.

```
columns.some((col, i) => {
    if (col.name !== keys[i]) {
        console.log('yes, I entered the if statement')
        //do something here
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried but, maybe my code is wrong, I need to return a false because I want to stop the whole code that is inside a function. I did it with a simple `for` instead. But your answer is correct, because I ask "how to do this with a forEach" explicity, and not "how can I loop an array and stop"